# Wordpress Drop Down Glitch on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm having difficulty with my drop down menu not showing up on mobile phones. It shows up and works on tablets but it's not working on the iphone specifically.

My code seems accurate but clearly something is preventing it from displaying correctly.

When you visit the site on an iphone (it may also do it on android) each button can be clicked but the buttons both submenu's and regular menu's aren't clickable with a drop down. It glitches a little bit as it expands too then nothing in a drop down menu can be clicked on but all the other menu items can be.

Any thoughts?

Here is the website: [www.smilesavvy.com](http://www.smilesavvy.com) 
It's the top menu navigation.

Here is my CSS too:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 1.24em 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}

nav li:hover a {
    background: #9fcf67;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

nav li ul {
    display: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav li:hover li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

nav li:hover li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 35px 7px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #9fcf67;
    color: #00456a;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

nav li:hover ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    background: #bbf774;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this IS the problem, but you have links on your main menu. On touchscreen devices hover is only fired when you "touch" on the elements (unless you use simulated mouse like in photon browser). However, this will also click the link thus will make it redirect to the destination website.

EDIT: it appeared that since you can't hover over the elements oh touchscreen devices, so when you tap on the sub-menu, it first cancelled the "hover" status, and make you click on the elements below it instead.

I would recommend using some methods to check if it's a mobile device or not. If it is then instead of hover, make it click to display or something like that. Or you can make a mobile site on a sub-domain, and use php to redirect the user to it when the user is on mobile.

Comment: Ya that was my first thought, however removing it still caused them to glitch and not function properly. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @VertigoSFX I think I've found the problem, check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Aister for the tip. I eventually want to do a mobile version. The problem i'm having here is i've used this code on other sites before, to build the drop down menus, even with the main link a link and it works. There is something specifically on this wordpress install causing issues.

For example, if you go to www.piedmontpd.com/new you'll notice on a phone that if you click a drop down button it activates the drop down then you can select the subpages, and it seems my wordpress site is trying to do that, but its just not activating the links. (Note: That piedmont site isn't done yet.)

Comment: @VertigoSFX the edited answer showed the way to do that, detecting if they are using mobile devices, and use jquery or javascript to set on click event listener on the main menu, which will open the submenu. Do you want me to further explain with code?

Comment: Oh ok I gotcha. No I think I can figure it out. Thanks.